# Greenfoot actor gets removed after compile

Tags: actor, greenfoot

I create a new scenario, add new world subclass, add a new actor subclass, then compile. I drag that new actor to the scenario and press the compile button and that actor disappears. Am I missing something here? I hope I am. I'm running this from the usb using the standalone version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actors you drag to the scenario are temporary - if you add them that way you have to drag them there each time you compile.

You've two options, either drag the actors where you want then right click the world and hit the "save the world" button, or edit the world's constructor to add your actors in where you want them.